# MinGW_w64 missing dll's

Tags: c, windows, gcc, dll, mingw-w64

I am trying to run a C compiler with Cython in a 64-bit Windows 7 platform.

After having various problems with the C compilers from Visual studio and MinGW32, I tried to install MinGW_w64. I did the following steps :

-I downloaded and extracted `winbuilds` from http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/win-builds, and I selected the Base GCC package with C support.

-I added `C:\PATH_TO_WINBUILDS` and `C:\PATH_TO_WINBUILDS\bin` in the `PATH` Windows environment variable.

-I wrote `helloworld.c`,  a very simple C program :

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

-Then in `cmd` I wrote:

```
gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld.exe
```

And a dialog box pops out with the following error message :

> Impossible to start program because libiconv.dll is missing on your computer. Reinstall program to correct problem.

The dll file does not appear in the `lib` folder of MinGW_w64. I tried to copy `libiconv.a` and `libiconv.dll.a` from the MinGW32 `lib` folder to the `lib` folder of MinGW_64, but still no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would recommend using a standalone installation of mingw-w64, not this "win-builds" (which looks like Yet Another poorly-maintained package manager).  For a minimal package manager for building unix-like software (but without full POSIX support), the MSYS2 project has much higher traffic.

Comment: This question is really about the "win-builds" project, not about C, gcc, or mingw-w64

Answer (score 1):

You need the DLL file, not the .a link library files. `libiconv.dll` should exist somewhere in the `bin` directory. If it is not there, you’ll need to get it from the internet or compile it yourself. Alternatively you could just link statically to the iconv library.

Once you find the DLL, make sure it is in one of the following locations:
 * the %PATH%
 * the appropriate `C:\Windows\system32` or `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` directory
 * (preferably) next to your executable

Comment: thanks for the tip, I found libiconv.dll on the internet, but it still does not work, I now have an error message : `The application did not start correctly (0xc000007b)`.

Comment: What does it mean to link statically to the iconv library? How do I do that? Cheers

Comment: put `-static` before the linkage: `g++ ... -static -liconv`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by downloading another version on the package on SourceForge.
Thanks!

Comment: That's not an answer.